# eclipseのプラグインでaputana studio3がインストールできない

Tags: eclipse

eclipseにaputana studio3というプラグインがあるらしく、これをインストールしたいのですが、インストールできません。

□やったこと
・javaのインストール
・eclipseプラットフォームのインストール
・eclipseの「ヘルプ」→「新規ソフトウェアのインストールに」（http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install）を入力

urlを入力しても候補に現れません。これはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: 公式ドキュメントにも記載のあるURLのようですが、指定したURLが現在利用できない状態なのが原因ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 指定したURLがオフラインだとの情報もあります。色々ありましたがあとはaputanastudioの導入だけなのですが・・・。検索しても全然情報が見つかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana StudioはStandalone版の最終が2014-11-15なので、割と放置されていると思われます。
[aptana / studio3 / 3.6.1.GA Releases](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/releases/tag/v3.6.1)

本体Webサイトの [News](http://www.aptana.com/news.html) の最新が2013-12-27なので、ここは全体的に保守されていないのでは？
なお、サポートのDiscussionは英語版StackOverflowの [ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aptana) にあり、類似の質問がありました。
[Aptana Studio 3 plugin fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718113/aptana-studio-3-plugin-fail)

上記をたどるとEclipseのMarketplaceに活動が移動しているようです。
[Home / Marketplace / Tools / Aptana Studio 3](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/aptana-studio-3)

上記の2017-06-29に、この投稿があり、Preview版でしょうがここにアクセスしてみてください。
I managed to install the plugin from following URL:
http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/rc/
it was mentioned by level420 on github.

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。無事にインストールできました。Rubyで総合開発環境を構築するのになんでこんなにたくさんのことをしないといけないのか疑問です。自分は甘いですね。